# How can I safely capture web-browser user's local time and send it to the backend for processing?

Tags: vue.js, go, web, time

I have a frontend application on Vue and I have a backend server on Golang.

My question is - how can I safely capture the user's local time and send it to the backend via API endpoint call.

The problem is, that when user opens a browser, the JS code is at that moment located inside user's browser, and user can change simple logic like `time = new Date().toString()` before sending it to the backend, which means, that user can fool the system.

How can I prevent that and safely capture the user's local time?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot. Nothing the user sends to you (directly or indirectly) can be trusted.

Answer (score -1):

You might not need the browser's local time but rather the timezone and the current server's time to calculate the user's time.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).